# jQuery Autocomplete not working - dropdown box not appearing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am having problem with jQuery Autocomplete. Everything seems to be working fine but the dropdown box does not appear.

The HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link href="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.core.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.autocomplete.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.menu.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> 
<script src="jQueryAssets/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="jQueryAssets/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<input type="text"  id="Autocomplete1">

<script src="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui-1.10.4.autocomplete.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $( "#Autocomplete1" ).autocomplete({
        source: "http://localhost:8888/Szczerapraca/search.php",
        autoFocus: true,
        minLength: 2,
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Now when I type in the data goes to search.php file:

[image]

And when query the file://localhost:8888/Szczerapraca/search.php?term=boo  it comes back with JSON array: ["Booking.com","Taboo.com"]

So everything looks fine until now, but the dropdown box never appears.

*I have tried changing z-index of the box to 1000 in CSS styling, but didn't help*

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're loading jqueryui twice, that could cause issues. Do you have any errors? If you inspect can you see the div for the autocomplete?

Comment: @Anthony Thompson
I have tried removing either of jqueryui files with no luck. In Firefox debugger there are no errors in console. Autocomplete was placed in <form></form> - I tried wrapping it in <div></div> but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking "response" in Firefox debugger (click on "network" tab and then on the data that was sent, additional options should appear) it turned out that the response was including html parts like   etc. Of course these did not appear when simply checking the URL in the browser. After removing html parts from search.php file everything works fine. D'oh!